# Graphviz で画像ファイルの出力及びエッジが無いノードを削除したい

Tags: graphviz

#### 前提

- 日毎にノード及びエッジが追加される
- エッジがつかないノードもある（後日，エッジがつく可能性もある）

#### 目的

- display(G)で表示される図をpng等の画像ファイルに保存したい
- エッジがないノードを最後に一括削除したい

#### コード

```
!pip install graphviz
```

```
from graphviz import Digraph

G = Digraph(format="png")
G.attr("node", fontname="Meiryo UI",fontsize='9',shape="circle")
G.attr(overlap='false',splines='true')

#クラスターの作成
with G.subgraph(name='cluster_root')as c:
c.attr(color='white',label='2022年')

#2022-01-06
with c.subgraph(name='cluster01-06')as c0106:
c0106.attr(color='red',label='01-06')
for node0106 in range(1092,1103):
c0106.node(str(node0106))

#2022-01-07
with c.subgraph(name='cluster01-07')as c0107:
c0107.attr(color='blue',label='01-07')
for node0107 in range(1103,1134):
c0107.node(str(node0107))

c0107edges=[(1103,1104),(1103,1105),(1103,1106),(1092,1119),(1092,1120),
(1092,1121),(1092,1122),(1092,1124),(1099,1124),(1101,1125),
(1101,1126),(1102,1127)]
for i,j in c0107edges:
c0107.edge(str(i),str(j),color="#00000080")

#2022-01-08
with c.subgraph(name='cluster01-08')as c0108:
c0108.attr(color='yellow',label='01-08')
for node0108 in range(1134,1184):
c0108.node(str(node0108))

c0108edges=[(1139,1140),(1139,1141),(1148,1149),(1113,1151),(1110,1152),
(1088,1153),(1117,1154),(1107,1155),
(1103,1157),(1103,1158),(1103,1159),(1103,1160),(1103,1161),
(1103,1162),(1103,1163),(1103,1164),(1103,1165),
(1118,1166),(1118,1167),(1123,1168),(1115,1169),(1128,1170),
(1128,1171),
(1117,1174),(1117,1175),(1117,1176),(1117,1177),(1117,1178),
(1117,1179),(1117,1180),(1117,1181)]
for i,j in c0108edges:
c0108.edge(str(i),str(j),color="#00000080")

display(G)
```

Answer (score 0):

> display(G)で表示される図をpng等の画像ファイルに保存したい

```py
G.view(filename='digraph')
```

> エッジがないノードを最後に一括削除したい

先の `G.view(filename='digraph')` を追加することで、実行ディレクトリに `digraph` という名前のファイル(`dot` 言語によるソースコード)が作成されます。`gvpr` コマンドがインストールされていれば、以下でエッジを持たないノードを削除してから PNG 形式のファイルを生成します。

```sh
$ gvpr -c 'N[$.degree==0]{delete(NULL, $)}' digraph | dot -Tpng -o digraph.png
```